# How to compare whether two inequalities are the same

Tags: compare, maxima

I have two complicated mathematical expressions inequalities. How can I best find out whether they
yield to the same solution set.

I have tried using the is(equal) method, but this does not check the unequal sign.

Comment: What are the expressions in question?

Comment: Quadratic inequalities are the most complex for my use case (so e.g. x^2+3x+2<6). But a more gneral approach (not only doable for polynomic functions) would be my goal